# Preventing addition of duplicate records

Tags: java, postgresql, jersey, query-optimization

Im using the following query to check if a question exists already in database.

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTBANK where QUESTION  = ?;
```

Following is the code in which I use the above query

```
public static boolean authQuestion(String question) throws SQLException {
    boolean isQuestionAvailable = false;
    Connection dbCon = null;
    try {
        dbCon = MyResource.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM QUESTBANK where QUESTION  = ?;";
        PreparedStatement checkStmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
        checkStmt.setString(1, question);
        ResultSet rs = checkStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            isQuestionAvailable = true;
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (dbCon != null)
            dbCon.close();
    } finally {
        if (dbCon != null)
            dbCon.close();
    }
    return isQuestionAvailable;
}
```

The problem is that It passes if the question text exactly matches. However, If an user add extra character and tries to add it to db, it is being added. How can I be able to efficiently prevent adding such duplicate records by optimising my query? and Of course the question might be multiline

Comment: If a person uses a synonym for the word and submit the same question, that'll be hard to indentify.

Comment: at a very basic level you could use the SQL keyword `LIKE` rather than equals

Comment: in addution to like, Postgres supports regular expression matching, including SQL regular expressions and POSIX Regular Expressions, you can try to build the condition that suits your needs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: it doesnt create a big difference....like query works much like equals..i tried it

Comment: What, exactly, do you consider to be a 'duplicate'? Is it just things that are equal regardless of punctuation? What about whitespace? Or synonyms? Or misspellings? What if a there's actually an incorrect word in the question which should be ignored? What you're trying to do is impossible if you treat the question as a simple String of characters, and is probably impossible to do perfectly, so what do you actually want to achieve?